# Carry Select Adder Scala Chisel

Tags: scala, hardware, chisel

I'm trying to implement a Carry Select Adder using Chisel in Scala. However after various efforts i keep getting errors. The ripple carry adder and multiplexers are tested and working. This is my current Version. Any Input is greatly appreciated!

```
class CarrySelectAdder(val n:Int, val m:Int) extends Module {
 val io = IO(new Bundle {
  val a    = Input(UInt(n.W))
  val b    = Input(UInt(n.W))
  val cin  = Input(UInt(1.W))
  val sum  = Output(UInt((n+1).W))
 })
 object carryselecthelper{                                                   //not used atm
  def n_sum_idx(stage:UInt) : UInt = {
    return stage * (stage + 1.U) / 2.U;
  }
 }

//val test = math.ceil(n/m)
val rcas   = Array.fill(2 * (n/m)){Module(new RcaAdder(m)).io}               //2*math.ceil(n/m)
val muxs   = Array.fill(n/m){Module(new Multiplexer(m+1)).io}                //math.ceil(n/m)
val Sum   = Wire(Vec(n, Bool()))

for (i <- 0 until n) {

  rcas(i*2).a := io.a.apply(i*m+m,i*m)
  rcas(i*2).b := io.b.apply(i*m+m,i*m)
  rcas(i*2).cin := 0.asUInt
  rcas(2*i+1).a := io.a.apply(i*m+m,i*m)
  rcas(2*i+1).b := io.b.apply(i*m+m,i*m)
  rcas(2*i+1).cin := 1.asUInt

  muxs(i).a := rcas(i*2).sum
  muxs(i).b := rcas(2*i+1).sum
  if(i > 0){
    muxs(i).sel := io.cin
  }
  if(i > 0){
    if(muxs(i).sel == 0){
      muxs(i).sel := rcas(2*i).cout
    }else{
      muxs(i).sel := rcas(2*i+1).cout
    }
  }
  
  Sum(i) := muxs(i).out
}

io.sum := Sum.asUInt
}
```

Currently I'm getting an Exception in "ChiselGeneratorAnnotation":

```
l3.internal.ChiselException: Exception thrown when elaborating ChiselGeneratorAnnotation
at chisel3.stage.ChiselGeneratorAnnotation.elaborate(ChiselAnnotations.scala:55)
ChiselAnnotations.scala:55
at chisel3.stage.phases.Elaborate.$anonfun$transform$1(Elaborate.scala:19)
Elaborate.scala:19
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
TraversableLike.scala:245
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
List.scala:392
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
TraversableLike.scala:245
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
TraversableLike.scala:242
at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
List.scala:355
at chisel3.stage.phases.Elaborate.transform(Elaborate.scala:18)
Elaborate.scala:18
at chisel3.iotesters.setupTreadleBackend$.apply(TreadleBackend.scala:143)
TreadleBackend.scala:143
at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.$anonfun$execute$2(Driver.scala:53)
Driver.scala:53
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
at logger.Logger$.$anonfun$makeScope$2(Logger.scala:168)
Logger.scala:168
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
DynamicVariable.scala:62
at logger.Logger$.makeScope(Logger.scala:166)
Logger.scala:166
at logger.Logger$.makeScope(Logger.scala:127)
Logger.scala:127
at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.$anonfun$execute$1(Driver.scala:38)
Driver.scala:38
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
DynamicVariable.scala:62
at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:38)
Driver.scala:38
```

Upon request I added the Multiplexer and RCA class, they should work fine, since they ran all tests without issues. Thanks!

```
class Multiplexer(val n:Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a    = Input(UInt(n.W))
    val b    = Input(UInt(n.W))
    val sel  = Input(UInt(n.W))
    val out  = Output(UInt(n.W))
  })
  
  io.out := (io.sel & io.a) | (~io.sel & io.b)

}



class RcaAdder(val n:Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a    = Input(UInt(n.W))
    val b    = Input(UInt(n.W))
    val cin  = Input(UInt(1.W))
    val sum  = Output(UInt(n.W))
    val cout = Output(UInt(1.W))
  })
  val FAs   = Array.fill(n){Module(new FullAdder()).io}
  val carry = Wire(Vec(n+1, UInt(1.W)))
  val sum   = Wire(Vec(n, Bool()))

  carry(0) := io.cin
  for (i <- 0 until n) {
    FAs(i).a := io.a(i)
    FAs(i).b := io.b(i)
    FAs(i).cin := carry(i)
    carry(i+1) := FAs(i).cout
    sum(i) := FAs(i).sum.asBool
  }
  io.sum := sum.asUInt
  io.cout := carry(n)
}
```

(This is what is used to test the code.)

```
class CarrySelectAdderTester(dut: CarrySelectAdder, n: Int) extends PeekPokeTester(dut) {
  val max=scala.math.pow(2,n).toInt-1
  for(i <- 0 to max){
    for (j <- 0 to max){
      for (k <- 0 to 1){
        poke(dut.io.a,i)
        poke(dut.io.b,j)
        poke(dut.io.cin,k)
        step(100)                  
        expect(dut.io.sum,(i+j+k))
      }
    }
  }
}

object CarrySelectAdderTester extends App{
  val bitWidth=6
  val bitsperblock=3
  println("Testing the Carry Select Adder")
  iotesters.Driver.execute(Array[String](), () => new CarrySelectAdder(bitWidth, bitsperblock)){
    c => new CarrySelectAdderTester(c,bitWidth)
  }

}
```

Comment: Code for the `RcaAdder` and `Multiplexer` are missing

Comment: Can you also post what you are using to generate the logic?

Comment: Code for RcaAdder, Multiplexer and code to test is added. Thanks Steveo!!

Comment: I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception on `rcas(i*2).a := io.a.apply(i*m+m,i*m)`. I also don't fully understand what the `apply` method is supposed to do in this case?

Comment: I want to get a subset of the input "a". E.g. a = "101001" and a.apply(2,0) = "001"

Comment: If you want 3bits, then your indexing should looks like `((i*(2*m))-1, (i*m))`. currently you are getting 1bit large then what you described. The `rcas(i*2)` is also indexing `rcas(4)` when `i==2` in the for loop. This is larger than what you have defined as you only have defined 4 `rcas`,  in which the highext index would be 3.